# multiple line within row-template in kendo-template bindings

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

I need a table structure using kendo binding for which I have a row-template and item-template ,as I had red telrik(kendo) documentation which says only one line is allowed within row-template.The requirement is that I want to have more than one row in row-template.But as soon as I add more than one line It renders only for the first row.

```
<script type="text/kendo-template" id="tableEditRows">
 <tr class="tableRow"  data-bind="source:cells" data-template="tableEditCell"></tr>
    <tr> 
        <td >testsal</td>
    </tr> 
  </script>
<script type="text/kendo-template" id="tableEditCell">
    <td class="tableCell" align="center">
        <p>value</p>
    </td>
</script> 
<div  id="numeric" ></div>
<script>
  var table = $('<table class="tableEdit"  style="width:200px">' +
                '<tbody align="center" data-bind="source:rows"  data-template="tableEditRows">');
                $("#numeric").append(table);
var viewModel = kendo.observable( {
  rows:[{
        cells:[{
                Id:1,
            Value:"asas"
      }]
  },{
        cells:[{
                Id:1,
            Value:"asas"
      }]
  }]
});
```

kendo.bind($("#numeric").get(0), viewModel);
here a link http://dojo.telerik.com/ifoBA/3 to that I am trying to do.
Is there a way to achieve having more than one line in row-template

Comment: have you looked into this example at all? http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy  From your question it appears you want to provide a parent ==> child grid solution.

Comment: I want to create a row that contains  the tables column values and beneath them another new TR that contains , additional information.
I did start out with using a RowTemplate that contained to <tr> tags but that creates problems only first row data is getting binded to the template not the second row

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by making use of static templating as I had a fixed set of rows.I created a html template within which I used a for loop for each row and for each rows I called a item-template within a `<tr>` tag. Along with this, I had a additional row template to how additional details.below is a code snippet to show what I had done.

```
        <script type="text/html" id="testTemplate" > 
         #for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){#
           <tr class="tableRow" data-bind="source:rows[#=i#].cells" data-template='tableEditCell'></tr>
           #if(rows[i].index==0){#
            <tr  >
                <td class="tableCell" >
                       some value
                </td>
            </tr>
              #}#
            #}#
        </script>
```

And here is the compiling and appending of template

```
var table = $('<table class="elvi"><tbody  align="center"></tbody></table>');
    var template = kendo.template($("#testTemplate").html());
      var itemHtml = template(self.viewModel);
                table.append(itemHtml);
                table.appendTo($(self.element));
```